# How to iterate through a list and use .isdigit to verify if a list of strings is made up of only digits or not

Tags: python

Write a function that takes, as an argument, a list, identified by the variable aList. If the list only contains elements containing digits (either as strings as integers), return the string formed by concatenating all of the elements in the list (see the example that follows). Otherwise, return a string indicating the length of the list, as specified in the examples that follow.

I am just starting to learn how to code and this is my first CS class.

```
def amIDigits(aList):
    for element in range(aList):
        if element in aList.isdigit():
            bList=[]
            bList.append(aList)
    return str(bList)
```

`amIDigits([“hello”, 23])` should return the string `“The length of the input is 2.”` 
`amIDigits ([“10”, “111”])` should return the string `“10111”`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right the output will be the joined digits even if they are not of the string format. So the best way is to use the `all` function (returns `true` if all elements of an iteration are `true`) and check if the string elements of the list are digits. If so, then return the `join` of all elements of the list converted to a string. Else, we return the length of the list using the new string formatting syntax (`f` represents string formatting and the `{}` return the result of an operation).

code:

```
def amIDigits(aList):
    if all([str(i).isdigit() for i in aList]):
        return ''.join(map(str,aList))
    else:
        return f'The length of the input is {len(aList)}.'
print(amIDigits(['hello', 23]))
print(amIDigits(['10', '111']))
print(amIDigits([55, 33]))
```

output:

```
The length of the input is 2.
10111
5533
```

Comment: I think it's a good idea to point out that in the `if` statement, the code (OP) is creating a new `list`, so it will only have one element. The `list` should be created outside of the loop to collect all the variables.

Comment: Igor, I typed in "amIDigits(1,2,3,4) in my shell and i received the following error "builtins.TypeError: amIDigits() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given". How do I get python to consider every digit or letter?

Comment: You cannot invoke this Python function directly from the shell. You would need to `import sys` at the top of your .py file and access `sys.argv[1]` through `sys.argv[4]`. Your problem does not state that you need to ask for user input (stdin) and print to the terminal/console/stdout. The output of a function goes to the calling program. User input and output is different from function input and output.

Comment: @Ryan is right. First of all, you need to write the function in shell in order to use it. Second, you need to pass a list, not 4 integers.

Comment: @PaulD You need to type in `amIDigits([1,2,3,4])`

Answer (score 0):

First, I highly recommend having someone literally sit down and have you walk them through your thought process. It is more useful as a learner to debug your thought process than to have someone give you the answer.

One thing I noticed is that you created your empty list, `bList`, inside the `for` block. This will not work. You need to create an empty list to store things into before you begin `for` looping through the old list, otherwise you will be over-writing your new list every time it loops. So right now, your `bList.append()` statement is appending an element onto an empty list every time it runs. (You will get only the very last element in the `aList` stored into your `bList`.)

Another problem is that you use the `range()` function, but you don't need to. You want to look at each element inside the list. Range creates a sequence of numbers from 0 to whatever number is inside the parentheses: [range() documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjwo63So7LgAhUEX60KHaUiCocQFjABegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fpython%2Fref_func_range.asp&usg=AOvVaw0FRoMhazzFHuErzuq8wPRk). Your code tries to pass a list into `range()`, so it is invalid.

The "`for` blank `in` blank" statement breaks up whatever list is in the second blank and goes through each of its elements one at a time. For the duration of the `for` statement, the first blank is the name of the variable that refers to the element being looked at. so for example:

```
apples = ["Granny Smith","Red Delicious","Green"]
for apple in apples:
  eat(apple) #yum!
```

The `for` `in` statement is more naturally spoken as "for each blank in blank:"